I want to build a community of people around me who strive to grow and contribute
My specific problem lies in finding people with the ambition to self-learn and do these sorts of things. As far as running a community, I know it can be like herding cats; but I feel confident with that part.
How exactly do you target these specific kinds of people who want to get together in person and work on projects that contribute in a significant way to people who deserve it, and stay motivated while doing it? Some people do this, but it is just a temporary "high". They never last long.
I would love some tips about finding these very specific ambitious people serious about their self-development who want to share.

I think the problem with your question is that you don't state what kind of project it is and how it works. It is quite important because it can be related to your failure. The point is that people who like to learn don't have to work in the same way as people who build some kind of certainty - for example your project.
